# Pandas concatenate from a list of dataframes not re using columns

Tags: pandas

I need to concatenate several pandas dataframe columns in a list. However, the pd.concat function is not re using columns that have the same name. In the following example, column "B" is in two of the dataframes but it doesn't get reused. When it gets concatenated, it makes a new "B" column and the whole dataframe ends up being one row.

```
import pandas as pd
data2 = {'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18]}
data3 = {'Name': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'Age': [4, 6, 419, 128]}
data4 = {'Name': ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], 'Age': [205, 721, 196, 148]}
test_df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
test_df2_transpose = test_df2.T
test_df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)
test_df3_transpose = test_df3.T
test_df4 = pd.DataFrame(data4)
test_df4_transpose = test_df4.T
test_list=[test_df2_transpose]
test_list.append(test_df3_transpose)
test_list.append(test_df4_transpose)
test_merge = pd.concat(test_list, axis=1, ignore_index=False)
print(test_merge)
```

I'm hoping to get a desired output like this:

```
Name,A,B,C,D,E,F,G
Age,20,21,19,18,NaN,NaN,NaN
Age,NaN,4,6,419,128,NaN,NaN
Age,NaN,NaN,NaN,205,721,196,148
```

Comment: what is your desired output? can you provide desired output as text table?

Comment: Those are not column names; they are values. Your columns are called `0`, `1`, `2` and `3` and regardless of that, columns won't get reused if you `concat` on `axis=1`, in that scenario it matches row index values instead.

Comment: Sorry I just editted it. I have the DataFrames generated with another method and I know that is correct but I just made some for this example.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data2 = {'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18]}
data3 = {'Name': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'Age': [4, 6, 419, 128]}
data4 = {'Name': ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], 'Age': [205, 721, 196, 148]}

data = [data2, data3, data4]    
out = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(i).set_index('Name').T for i in data])
```

out

```
Name     A     B     C      D      E      F      G
Age   20.0  21.0  19.0   18.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
Age    NaN   4.0   6.0  419.0  128.0    NaN    NaN
Age    NaN   NaN   NaN  205.0  721.0  196.0  148.0
```